# What does the "On Error Resume Next" statement do?

Tags: vbscript, error-handling

I came to some VBScript examples, and I saw the statement `On Error Resume Next` basically at the beginning of the script.

What does it do?

Comment: It is a very powerful, but dangerous bit of syntax. Be very cautious using it.

Comment: It makes more sense now. After some functions that can end up in error. They have a function called checkError after them.

Comment: yes, it's 2018, but this is still valid - `On Error Resume Next` is like saying 'I think this thing should work, but if it doesn't work, act like it did`. in reality causing a lot of headache to future maintainers. avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It basically tells the program when you encounter an error just continue at the next line.

Answer (score 50):

It's worth noting that even when `On Error Resume Next` is in effect, the Err object is still populated when an error occurs, so you can still do C-style error handling.

```
On Error Resume Next

DangerousOperationThatCouldCauseErrors

If Err Then
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "error " & Err.Number
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 24):

When an error occurs, the execution will continue on the next line without interrupting the script.

Answer (score 11):

It means, when an error happens on the line, it is telling vbscript to continue execution without aborting the script. Sometimes, the `On Error` follows the `Goto` label to alter the flow of execution, something like this in a `Sub` code block, now you know why and how the usage of `GOTO` can result in spaghetti code:

```
Sub MySubRoutine()
   On Error Goto ErrorHandler

   REM VB code...

   REM More VB Code...

Exit_MySubRoutine:

   REM Disable the Error Handler!

   On Error Goto 0

   REM Leave....
   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

   REM Do something about the Error

   Goto Exit_MySubRoutine
End Sub
```

Comment: VBScript doesn't support the `On Error Goto Label` syntax, only `On Error Goto 0`.

Answer (score 6):

It enables error handling. The following is partly from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx

```
' Enable error handling. When a run-time error occurs, control goes to the statement 
' immediately following the statement where the error occurred, and execution
' continues from that point.
On Error Resume Next

SomeCodeHere

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "No Error in SomeCodeHere."
Else
  WScript.Echo "Error in SomeCodeHere: " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Source & ", " & Err.Description
  ' Clear the error or you'll see it again when you test Err.Number
  Err.Clear
End If

SomeMoreCodeHere

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Error in SomeMoreCodeHere:" & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Source & ", " & Err.Description
  ' Clear the error or you'll see it again when you test Err.Number
  Err.Clear
End If

' Disables enabled error handler in the current procedure and resets it to Nothing.
On Error Goto 0

' There are also `On Error Goto -1`, which disables the enabled exception in the current 
' procedure and resets it to Nothing, and `On Error Goto line`, 
' which enables the error-handling routine that starts at the line specified in the 
' required line argument. The line argument is any line label or line number. If a run-time 
' error occurs, control branches to the specified line, making the error handler active. 
' The specified line must be in the same procedure as the On Error statement, 
' or a compile-time error will occur.
```

Answer (score 3):

On Error Statement  - Specifies that when a run-time error occurs, control goes to the statement immediately following the statement. How ever Err object got populated.(Err.Number, Err.Count etc)

Answer (score 0):

On Error Resume Next means that On Error, It will resume to the next line to resume.

e.g. if you try the Try block, That will stop the script if a error occurred

Comment: Using Try/catch does not work for me in VBA (Excel 2016) nor VBScript.