# How can i run the script without showing me errors

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim filesys
oShell.Run "taskkill /F /IM mysqld.exe", , True
Dim WShell
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
file = ("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe")
fso.DeleteFile file
Set WShell = Nothing
```

Im getting permission denied running the script with user privileges, what i want is that the script wont display that error even if i get permission denied.

Comment: [What does the “On Error Resume Next” statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202869/what-does-the-on-error-resume-next-statement-do)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [On Error - statement of language VBScript](https://www.promotic.eu/en/pmdoc/ScriptLangs/VBScript/Statmn/OnError.htm)

If you don't use an `On Error Resume Next` statement, then any runtime error that occurs is fatal;
 i.e. an error message is displayed and the execution stops.

`On Error Resume Next` causes execution to continue with the statement immediately following the statement that caused the runtime error, or with the statement immediately following the most recent call out of the procedure containing the `On Error Resume Next` statement.

This allows execution to continue despite a runtime error. You can then build the error-handling routine inline within the procedure.

An `On Error Resume Next` statement becomes inactive if another procedure is called, so you should execute an `On Error Resume Next` statement in each called routine if you want inline error handling within that routine.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim fso,oShell,file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "Taskkill /F /IM mysqld.exe",0,True
file = "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"
If fso.FileExists(file) Then
    fso.DeleteFile file
End If
Set oShell = Nothing 
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add something more in error handling:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim filesys
oShell.Run "taskkill /F /IM mysqld.exe", , True
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = ("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe")
On Error Resume Next
fso.DeleteFile file
On Error Goto 0
Set fso = Nothing
```

You can disable error handling any time using `On Error Goto 0` statement.
And there is an `Err` object.
`Err.Raise ErrorCode` raises an error using an errorcode. `Err.Number` gives the error code and `Err.Description` gives the error details.